# Why is Chrome showing extra line when using Google org chart?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-visualization

I am using [Google org chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart) and it works great on every browser except Chrome.  On  Chrome I see these extra lines in between the boxes like this:

[image: Chrome browser]

For all other browsers, the same page shows up as this:

[image: Other browser]

As you can see there are no blue lines in between the nodes.  When I look in firebug or chrome dev tools it appears that its:

```
.google-visualization-orgchart-node

border: 2px solid #b5d9ea;
```

That is causing the issue because if i change the border to 0px then the issue goes away (but the border on the actual nodes also goes away which is obviously an issue.

Any suggestion for how to render this correctly in Chrome.  I don't see this issue happening in the demo link above.

Comment: Can you reproduce the bug in a fiddle?

Comment: I have just tried and It does not do that to me https://jsfiddle.net/xhiena/wd1kLdg5/2/

Comment: can you show the original code / is it public? maybe the sourcecode of the rendered site from chrome?

Comment: Can you also post exactly which version of Chrome has this issue? (I also don't see it in Pablo Martinez' fiddle, either on 48.0.2564.109, or 50.0.2657.0)

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using? I cannot reproduce this issue on 48.0.2564.116.

Comment: It looks like your browser is adding the blue focus line on all your objects (as this is what Chrome does and other browsers not). You might want to try adding this your CSS: `*:focus { outline: none; }` and see if it solves the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.google-visualization-orgchart-linenode {
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: this wasn't the exact correct answer but it led me to the css that i had that was overriding by accident so i ahve accepted the answer and awarded the bounty

Comment: Remember to delete browser cache data, this was my error and the reason of this code didn't work... but now it's working :D

Answer (score 17):

In my case it was Bootstrap 3 with

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

that was the cause. Fixed it with setting

```
table.google-visualization-orgchart-table {
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Comment: This is my problem as well!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have any border rule applied for this css class 
.google-visualization-orgchart-linenode

Answer (score 0):

I would try Patrick's answer of setting the `.google-visualization-orgchart-linenode {border: 0}`. If that doesn't work try setting the `border-collapse` property since its [separate by default](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp).

```
.google-visualization-orgchart-table,
.google-visualization-orgchart-table tr,
.google-visualization-orgchart-table td {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Although that's weird that its only showing in Chrome for you. Make sure you have [your DOCTYPE setup correctly](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Set the nodeClass option on the chart.draw with a color and background-color to override the default color scheme, which solves the problem in Chrome.

Set two css classes:

```
//css class for default tree node
.default-leaf { color:black; background-color:#DCDCDC; }

// css class for selected tree node
.selected-leaf { color:white; background-color:#191970; }
```

While initializing the chart set the nodeClass & selectedNodeClass options:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart( document.getElementById('chart_div'));

// setting options - allowHtml (required for visuals to work), css classes for a tree-node & selected-tree-node
var options = { 'allowHtml': true, 'nodeClass': 'default-leaf', 'selectedNodeClass': 'selected-leaf'};
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I added to stop the random lines from showing up

```
<style>
    table{
        border-collapse: separate !important;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

We had an incompatibility with normalize.css that caused this same issue for us. Adding the following CSS fixed it:

```
table.google-visualization-orgchart-table {
  border-collapse: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also added the following to fix the issue:

```
table {
border-collapse: separate!important; 
}
```